# graphs divisibility

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, division

Given a simple undirected graph containing N vertices numbered 1 to N, each vertex containing a digit from {1,2,..7}. Starting at the vertex 1 with an empty string S, we travel through some vertices (with no limitations) to the vertex N. For every vertex on the way, we add the respective digit to the right of the string S. At last we get S as a decimal integer. You are requested to find such a way satisfying S is divisible by all of its digits, and the sum of digits of S must be as small as possible.

Input

There are several test cases (fifteen at most), each formed as follows:

```
The first line contains a positive integer N (N ≤ 100).
The second line contains N digits (separated by spaces), the i-th digit is the value of the i-th vertex.
N last lines, each contains N values of {0, 1} (separated by spaces), the j-th value of the i-th line is equal to 1 if there is an edge connecting two vertices (i, j), otherwise 0.
```

The input is ended with N = 0.

Output

For each test case, output on a line the minimum sum of digits found, or -1 if there's no solution.

example

Input:
4

1 2 1 4

0 1 1 1

1 0 0 1

1 0 0 1

1 1 1 0

Output:
7

please guide me

there can be self loops and cycles such that node 1 and node N can be visted any number of times

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should use the homework tag. What have you done so far?

Comment: not a homework ...just a programming problem. Actually i figured that if the last set contains a 5 then there can not be any even number.And also in case if the number contains a 4 then last 2 digits should be divisble by 4. So i started traversing the graph from the end.And for 7 as I used octal divisibility.My program works but it takes a lot of time to evaluate for higher values of N.So please help me with a faster method

Answer (score 2):

If given graph is transformed to some other graph, where cycles are not allowed, this problem can be solved with [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

To do this, let's start with string divisibility by 7. Look at this sequence: 1, 10, 100, ... (mod 7). Since 7 is a prime number, 10<sup>7-1</sup> = 1 (mod 7) because of [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). Which means 1, 10, 100, ... (mod 7) sequence is periodic and period is 6. This will be used to transform the graph and also this allows to recursively compute S<sub>n</sub> (mod 7) using S<sub>n-1</sub> (mod 7): S<sub>n</sub> = S<sub>n-1</sub> + 10<sup>n%6</sup> * n_th_digit (mod 7).

It's necessary to start shortest path search from node N because this path may be ended at one of the several nodes of the transformed graph. Also this allows to determine quickly (using first 2 nodes of the path), if it is allowed to visit node "5", node"4", and other "even" nodes.

Algorithm's open set (the priority queue) should contain the priority itself (sum of digits) as long as 3 additional bits and 3 remainders: is "4" allowed, is "3" visited, is "7" visited, `S % 3`, `S % 7`, and `S.length % 6`.

Graph should be transformed as follows. Each vertex is expanded to 3 vertexes, one is allowed only for `S%3==0`, others - for `S%3==1` and `S%3==2`. Then each vertex is expanded to 7 (for `S%7`), and then each vertex is expanded to 6 (for `S.length % 6`). It is possible to fit all these expansions to the original graph: just add a 3D array (size 3*7*6) of back-pointers to each node. While searching for the shortest path, the non-empty back-pointers determine algorithm's closed set (they disallow cycles). When shortest path is found, back-pointers allow to reconstruct the sequence of nodes in this path. And the moment when shortest path is found is determined by visiting node 1 with `(node_3_not_visited || S%3==0) && (node_7_not_visited || S%7==0)`.

Comment: but my problem needs to handle loops

Comment: @user1380294: this solution uses *loopless* modified graph to find the shortest path. But if you map this graph back to the original graph, you have a graph *with loops*.

Comment: Then each vertex is expanded to 7 (for S%7), and then each vertex is expanded to 6 (for S.length % 6) what does it mean?

Comment: @rakeshkumar: this means each vertex in the original array is represented as a 3d array of vertexes of size 3*6*7. Edges, coming from some neighbor vertex, are also split into 126 edges, coming to each of these vertexes. But only one of these edges is allowed for given path: it must match attributes S % 3, S % 7, and S.length % 6 of the path. In practice, doing this explicitly is possible, but too expensive, so we may use original edges and original vertexes, each vertex with a 3d array of back-pointers.

Answer (score 0):

First mathematically find the LCM of the numbers given in the set.

lemme paraphrase the scenario .... given a set of numbers... find the LCM then traverse the vetices in such a way that the their path makes the number .Since its LCM it is number whose sum is mininum

For set {0,1,2,3,4} LCM is 12 so travers from 1 to 2 
for set {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} LCM is 420..(I think i am right)

Comment: but the size of the string can be very large in that case finding LCM is extremely difficult and then traversing the graph with loops will exceed time limit –

Comment: In the question it was given that the we need to form the string based on the constraints given... okay so if given number n is very large suppose 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,90,10,11,12,13,14,15 then LCM of 2,4,8 is 8 and 3,6,12 is 12  and 5,10 is 10 and 7,14 is 14 and we are left with 7,11,13,12,10,14,8 so taking LCM is mostly dependent on numbers of primes number less than N others are grouped like the way they are grouped above.. and second thing when N is very large your question seems to be an interesting optimization

Comment: N is the number of nodes and value of each node will be from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.I think you misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

Use the [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) search algorithm, where the "cost" is the sum of the digits, and divisibility determines which edges you can traverse.

Comment: actually i already used A* but time complexity is very high because of loops and self loops

Comment: Right, so A* is polynomial when the search space is a tree, there is a single goal state, and the heuristic function h is (to paraphrase) not far off. Do you need it less polynomial, or do you experience exponential timing?

Comment: i am experiencing exponential timing because of loops.

Comment: how about labelling all nodes with minimum distance (in terms of smallest sum) to N and including that in the cost?

Comment: @andrewcooke but how will it help in saving time.

Comment: it will increase the cost for repeated loops far from the endpoint, which seems to be the problem you are having (i think?).  currently your cost only includes the digits included so far - what i am suggesting is also include the future digits required, at a minimum, to get to N.

Comment: (in other words, it will prioritize getting to the endpoint).

Comment: but suppose there is no string which is divisible by its digits then there will be no stopping criteria as there could be loops.

Comment: i cannot completely avoid a loop . as a loop could be in the answer string

Comment: Oh, my mistake for not noticing that in the question posed. In that case, I'd say your problem is [NP-hard](http://xkcd.com/287/), so you can't do better than exponential.